# Firebug 1.10.0 breakpoints, hit after x times

Tags: javascript, firebug, breakpoints

is it possible to make a break point in an arbitrary JavaScript file and make it so Firebug stops/debugs the program only after it's been hit x number of times?

I've been playing around with adding expressions to the breakpoints but haven't gotten that to work yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's currently not possible but I created an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=2817) for that some time ago.
Currently work on moving Firebug to a [new debugging API](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5421) has started, which will - as soon as it is implemented - allow implementing this feature.